# Question on medical terms in crutch gait

Tags: discussion, scope

I quite recently asked [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/285956/) regarding medical terminology on a variation of crutch gait at English Language Learners SE (English is not my primary language).

The question drew some concerns/criticism in the comments as being very specialized and therefore not particularly suited for ELL.

I read the help pages and the ["terminology" question](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/38) here on Medical Sciences, but I'm not entirely sure if the question would fit here either.

Would some experienced community members be so kind to tell me their judgement? If it's deemed appropriate for this SE, I would seek the question to be migrated.

Comment: This [web site](https://www.verywellhealth.com/how-to-walk-safely-with-crutches-2696295) was given to you in a comment on your question on ELL. Does it not answer the question? If not, you at least need to acknowledge it in your question here or risk having it downvoted and possibly closed for lack of prior research.

Comment: @CareyGregory Prior research, including what was recommended in the comments, is now included. Unfortunately, I was not able to find something on any of these pages. My best guess it's not something you would want a patient to do and is therefore left out when describing what they should to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your edits I'd say the question would be fine here, but you should think carefully before acting. It already has upvotes and two upvoted answers, and there's no guarantee you'll get any answers here. In fact, I would bet you won't because language questions don't tend to draw much interest here. It also appears possible this gait doesn't have a name.

There's also the question of how the ELL mods will handle this. They may not be willing to migrate it, and now that it has answers you can't delete it. If you simply copy and paste it here without it first being removed on ELL, it will almost certainly be deleted as a cross-posted duplicate.

I think your best course of action is do nothing for now. If it gets closed on ELL, you can then post it here.

Comment: Thanks for your time looking into this. I think I will follow your recommendation and wait and see how it works out. My life does not depend on me knowing the exakt word that one might use for this, it was mainly curiosity.